# I am using loopback to scaffold an application, can I still write my code as an express application instead of using some of their components?

Tags: node.js, express, loopbackjs, oauth-2.0

I have used loopback to scaffold out my application but want to use some of their components, their documentation is lacking, can I just enable the functionality I want like I would using just express?

Specifically, I want to implement OAuth2

Comment: Don't know why you got downvoted, but it was not deserved. Perfectly legit question.

Answer (score 0):

The `loopback` object is directly the express object (with all the loopback sweet additions of course). You can obtain this object by requiring the `server.js` file scaffolded in your application.

So you can do everything express does with it, like routing for instance

```
var app = require('server.js').    
app.get('/', function (req, res) {
   res.send('Hello World!');
});
```

Implementing OAuth2 is absolutely possible (done it myself, without using oauth loopback plugin), nothing preventing it, but it's not exactly straightforward. I would advise to spend some time getting familiar with loopback and building a few small applications first.